# Error: Variable referenced before assignment - WHY?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the following:

```
protein = macros_p / 4
```

> UnboundLocalError: local variable `macros_p` referenced before assignment

The arguments for the function `(goal, body_type, daily_exp) aren't an issue because I've used them in prior functions without a problem but this one isn't working and it's seriously stumping me.

Can anyone please explain?

```
def macros(goal, body_type, daily_exp):
    if goal == "L" and body_type == "Ectomorph":
        daily_exp = (daily_exp - 200)
        macros_p = (daily_exp * 0.25)
        macros_c = (daily_exp * 0.55)
        macros_f = (daily_exp * 0.2)
    elif goal == "L" and body_type == "Mesomorph":
        daily_exp = (daily_exp - 250)
        macros_p = (daily_exp * 0.4)
        macros_c = (daily_exp * 0.3)
        macros_f = (daily_exp * 0.3)
    elif goal == "L" and body_type == "Endomorph":
        daiy_exp = (daily_exp - 500)
        macros_p = (daily_exp * 0.5)
        macros_c = (daily_exp * 0.1)
        macros_f = (daily_exp * 0.4)

    protein = (macros_p / 4)
    carbs = (macros_c / 4)
    fat = (macros_f / 9)
    print("Daily intake: " + str(daily_exp) + " calories")
    print(str(protein) + "g Protein")
    print(str(carbs) + "g Carbohydrates")
    print(str(fat) + "g Fat")
```

Comment: If all of your conditions evaluate to false, none of the `macros` variables will be set. Either `goal` and/or `body_type` aren't what you think they are. Show the data being given to `macros`.

Comment: `daily_exp` is a parameter, so it does exists. But maybe, for `macros_p` no one of your `if statements` is being executed, for instance, when you want to print its value it hasn't be referenced. Put a `else` statement and print out the value of `macros_p`

Comment: Random guess: you spelled the `body_type` wrong. Strings like that are dangerous because they're susceptible to typos, and those are long words. Or, you have a trailing newline in one of the parameters.

Comment: As said, add `else: print "unknown type" + str(body_type)`, then raise an error message yourself.

Comment: Earlier in the program when the user's prompted to enter their goal and then body_type they have to choose one of the existing options as anything else will return "ERROR! Invalid entry" and loop them back within that function to re-enter. I've checked and the spelling for the strings is correct. Also, the code is longer but it repeats what you see here but with different multiplications... Here's the full program with this part starting on line 146 if anyone's interested: https://gist.github.com/gracehparker/a366381049472263f62bdac9d1f9c80a#file-macro-nutrient-calculator

Comment: @GraceParker Show an [mvce] here with the *exact* data being given to this function. The only possible way that the error you're describing could happen is if all the conditions are conditions fail, and the only way for that to happen is for one of the string parameters to be wrong, and the only was to diagnose that is to see the exact data being checked. Check the parameters with `list(goal + body_type)` to make sure there are no invisible characters in there.

Comment: Whoops, that should have said `[mcve]` for [mcve].

Comment: The issue wasn't in the macros function but in the body_type function - I hadn't indented some of it and so the body_type was being saved as "1", "2" or "3" instead of "Ectomorph", "Mesomorph" or "Endomorph". You guys were still a big help as I thought I had just missed something in that function being a newb and so sharing what you did forced me to take a look at the rest. Thank you!